# Generar archivo excel y enviarlo por correo electrónico con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

Tengo un formulario en el que obtengo registros al filtrar fecha de inicio y fecha final, logré generar(se descarga) un excel del resultado de la consulta, también tengo campos donde puedo ingresar un correo cualquiera para poder enviar el excel, lo que necesito es enviar ese excel generado a un correo, estoy usando la biblioteca *PHPexcel*.

Les dejo mi código php

```
<?php
 require_once("../conexion.php");
 $conexion = new conexion();
 $con = $conexion->conn();
 require_once('../Classes/PHPExcel.php');
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

 $To = $_POST['Para'];
 $CC = $_POST['CC'];
 $Tema = $_POST['Tema'];
 $TypeHhtml  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $TypeHhtml .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

 $Cabezera  = $TypeHhtml;
 $Cabezera .= $Tema;
 $Contenido .= $_POST['Contenido'];

 $FecIni = $_POST['inicio'];
 $FecFin = $_POST['fin'];




$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Obed Alvarado")
  ->setLastModifiedBy("Obed Alvarado")
  ->setTitle("Office 2010 XLSX Documento de prueba")
  ->setSubject("Office 2010 XLSX Documento de prueba")
  ->setDescription("Documento de prueba para Office 2010 XLSX, generado 
  usando clases de PHP.")
  ->setKeywords("office 2010 openxml php")
  ->setCategory("Archivo con resultado de prueba");

  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A1:O1');

   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hola')
        ->setCellValue('A2', 'SOLICITUD')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'NOMBRES')
        ->setCellValue('C2', 'APELLIDOS')
        ->setCellValue('D2', 'CORREO')
        ->setCellValue('E2', 'TELEFONO')
       ->setCellValue('F2', 'EDAD')
       ->setCellValue('G2', 'SEXO')
       ->setCellValue('H2', 'OCUPACION')
       ->setCellValue('I2', 'DISTRITO')
       ->setCellValue('J2', 'VISITANTE')
      ->setCellValue('K2', 'MEDIO')
      ->setCellValue('L2', 'FRECUENCIA')
      ->setCellValue('M2', 'ENTRADA')
      ->setCellValue('N2', 'DESCUENTO')
      ->setCellValue('O2', 'MENSAJE')
      ->setCellValue('P2', 'FECHA INGRESO');

      // Fuente de la primera fila en negrita
      $boldArray = array('font' => array('bold' => true,),'alignment' => array('horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER));

      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:N2')->applyFromArray($boldArray);  

      //Ancho de las columnas
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(20);  
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);  
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(15);  
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(50);  
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(20);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setWidth(20);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(20);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setWidth(20);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('I')->setWidth(20);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('J')->setWidth(20);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('K')->setWidth(20);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('L')->setWidth(20);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('M')->setWidth(20);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('N')->setWidth(20);
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('O')->setWidth(20);
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('P')->setWidth(20);

      $sql="SELECT * FROM solicitador WHERE fecharegistro BETWEEN '$FecIni 00:00:00' AND '$FecFin 00:00:00'";
      $result=$con->query($sql);
      $cel=4;//Numero de fila donde empezara a crear  el reporte
      while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
       $Id_Solicitud=$row['Id_Solicitud'];
       $Nombres=$row['Nombres'];
       $Apellidos=$row['Apellidos'];
       $Correos=$row['Correo'];
       $Telefono=$row['Telefono'];
       $Edad=$row['Edad'];
       $Sexo=$row['Sexo'];
       $Ocupacion=$row['Ocupacion'];
       $Distrito=$row['Distrito'];
       $Visitante=$row['Visitante'];
       $Medio=$row['Medio'];
       $Frecuencia=$row['Frecuencia'];
       $Adq_Entrada=$row['Adq_Entrada'];
       $Descuento=$row['Descuento'];
      $Mensaje=$row['Mensaje'];
      $fecharegistro=$row['fecharegistro'];

      $a="A".$cel;
      $b="B".$cel;
      $c="C".$cel;
      $d="D".$cel;
      $e="E".$cel;
      $f="F".$cel;
      $g="G".$cel;
      $h="H".$cel;
      $i="I".$cel;
      $j="J".$cel;
      $k="K".$cel;
      $l="L".$cel;
     $m="M".$cel;
     $n="N".$cel;
     $o="O".$cel;
     $p="P".$cel;
  // Agregar datos
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue($a, $Id_Solicitud)
        ->setCellValue($b, $Nombres)
        ->setCellValue($c, $Apellidos)
        ->setCellValue($d, $Correos)
  ->setCellValue($e, $Telefono)
  ->setCellValue($f, $Edad)
        ->setCellValue($g, $Sexo)
        ->setCellValue($h, $Ocupacion)
        ->setCellValue($i, $Distrito)
  ->setCellValue($j, $Visitante)
  ->setCellValue($k, $Medio)
        ->setCellValue($l, $Frecuencia)
        ->setCellValue($m, $Adq_Entrada)
        ->setCellValue($n, $Descuento)
        ->setCellValue($o, $Mensaje)
        ->setCellValue($p, $fecharegistro);

   $cel+=1;
   }


   $rango="A2:$p";
   $styleArray = array('font' => array( 'name' => 'Arial','size' => 10),'borders'=>array('allborders'=>array('style'=>PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,'color'=>array('argb' => 'FFF'))));
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($rango)->applyFromArray($styleArray);


   // Cambiar el nombre de hoja de cálculo
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('hola amigos');


   // Establecer índice de hoja activa a la primera hoja , por lo que Excel abre esto como la primera hoja
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Excel.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');




    $MSM = mail($To,$Tema,$objPHPExcel,$Cabezera);
    if($MSM){
      print "Se envio el mensaje";
     //mail($CC,$Tema,$Contenido,$Cabezera);
    }else{
         print "No se pudo enviar el mensaje";
     }
      echo $Imprimir;
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aclaro solo algunas cosas:

1. La función **mail** de php, trabaja sobre un SMTP previamente configurado (se configura en el archivo php.ini). Si no configuraste nada , no va a funcionar.
2. $objWriter->save('php://output'): 'php://output' es un flujo que te permite escribir un buffer de salida (como cuando usamos el eco "echo" ), esto lo que va a hacer es "escupir" lo que sería el archivo excel. Vos lo que necesitarías no es enviar el excel al buffer de salida ese, sino retenerlo para su envío (o guardarlo y enviarlo seguido):

//guardo el archivo localmente, de paso me queda en caso de que el envío falle:

$objWriter->save('/ruta/a/miArchivo.xlsx');

3. Personalmente te recomiendo usar librerías más simples como [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#a-simple-example):  Ya que te va a facilitar mucho el envío de correos (y de paso te vas a ahorrar un troubleshooting muy extenso que tiene la función mail por detrás).

Espero que te ayude. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
// Activa el almacenamiento en búfer de la salida
ob_start();
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5')
$objWriter->save('php://output');
//Obtener el contenido del búfer actual y eliminar el búfer de salida actual
$excelOutput = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._ ¡No olvides explicar qué hace el código!